# how to make this cube responsive?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

here is my code for rotating cube. Am trying to make it responsive.

But am not getting it. Here is my code [`sample`](http://jsfiddle.net/hvmvkhvx/).

Is it possible to make it responsive ?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: @lv0gun9 thanks for your comment. It should be responsive. if suppose i resize browser size then cube size also resize accordingly.

Comment: IMO, It will be possible. but useless. I think it will be too slow.